# 3d solid identification

Tags: geometry, 3d

Let me try to describe it:
- start with a cylinder or tube
- collapse (squeeze) base of the cylinder until it becomes a segment
- rotate 90 degrees along the height axis
- collapse (squeeze) other base of the cylinder until it becomes a segment

As circular bases become segments the net you would use to build it is just rectangular.

Thanks

Comment: You asked the identical question yesterday. The picture you posted there is a tetrahedron. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132304/what-is-the-name-of-3d-shape

Comment: You are absolutely right Ethan.   Lets move on now to a little experiment.    Take a sheet of paper and roll it into tube.   Now use piece of tape and close it like a toothpaste tube.   Move to other end.   This time rotate the paper tube 90 degrees and then tape it again.   What shape is that? You must agree it has only two edges therefore it is not tetrahedron...

Comment: Not (yet) voting to close, but it's no clearer what you're asking here than it is at your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132304). Do you just want the name of this type of object? Do you care about 1. Intrinsic geometry, in which case you have a tetrahedron; 2. Extrinsic geometry, in which case I don't know of a standard name (though "conical tetrahedron" would be descriptive); 3. Topology, in which case you have a sphere; or 4. Something else?

Comment: I am just looking for a name...

Answer (score 1):

I agree that figure you care about isn't a tetrahedron (the picture in the same question yesterday). I agree that it's an interesting figure. I'm pretty sure it doesn't have a name. Maybe I'm wrong and someone will know the name.

I think that topologically your figure is an [orbifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold).

Here's an image with one circle flattened:
[image]
https://www.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/Gallery/Symmetry/Tilings/22S/PlasticBag.html

There's no way to express in purely topological terms the fact that the other flattening is rotated 90 degrees. You need some kind of metric information for that.

Comment: If we assume that first closure is horizontal the other one would be vertical.

Comment: I understand that. But it's not a topological property.